# is there any API in google classroom which returns the google meet address?

Tags: openapi, google-classroom, google-meet

I want to get the google meet address as a response after creating the course in google classroom api. I couldn't find any API. If possible please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is an active feature request

> ### https://issuetracker.google.com/156772382

Go over and star it to let Google know that you are interested in it, and that way also subscribe to future updates.

Answer (score 0):

Meet links etc. within Google Classroom aren't exposed yet via the [API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest). Fingers crossed for the near future.